# How to center two blocks with some gap inbetween using CSS?

Tags: html, css, alignment

What I would like to reach is the following design:

[image]

Two text blocks with some gaps inbetween aligned around the page midline (see the picture).

I tried to play around with `float` property, using `margin` and `padding` to get the gap, but I can't get them centered.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to indicate that the arrows show the resizable parts: so, the page width must be resizeable whereas the text itself isn't, but the text is dynamic content and can change from page to page, so there is no way to just define constant width for it in pixels.

Comment: Have you tried combining a table with align?

Comment: Which parts are fixed width, and which parts change width when the window is resized?

Comment: @Anton: Yes, tables are the current solution, but I want to eliminate all tables in my design where I don't need them and use CSS.

Comment: @thirtydot You are completely right, I have forgot to mention it in my answer. Now I added this info to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
<div id="wrapper">       <!-- wrapper will be in the middle of the page -->
   <div id="box1"></div> <!-- Your First Box -->
   <div id="box2"></div> <!-- Second Box -->
</div>

#wrapper { width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto }
#box1 { width: 400px; float: left; }
#box2 { width: 400px; float: right; }
/* There Will be 200px gap in between of two boxes */
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!! I forgot to mention that the page width has to be resizeable. The text is dynamic and can be of different width, so there is no way to set its width to a constant value a priori. Sorry for not mentioning it in the beginning!!

Comment: The above solution will still work with percentages, for example:
body { width:100%; }
#wrapper { width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; }
#box1 { width: 45%; float: left; }
#box2 { width: 45%; float: right; }

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: table` with `margin: 0 auto` for centered block and `display: table-cell` with percentage `padding` for its children. Set percentage `width` for centered block if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NTWYC/)?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="column">
<div class="column1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi in libero interdum ante vulputate viverra non vehicula sapien. Sed ac posuere sapien. Morbi a massa leo, sed hendrerit odio. Aliquam in diam in mauris elementum fringilla. Maecenas vestibulum massa at massa imperdiet eu venenatis velit sagittis. Donec nec libero vel ipsum mattis cursus. Ut vel tortor id lectus rhoncus laoreet. Aliquam volutpat rhoncus arcu et euismod. Phasellus pulvinar condimentum lacus non dictum. In nisi lorem, ultrices quis convallis vel, consectetur vulputate arcu. Quisque malesuada bibendum nulla, at facilisis quam facilisis sed. Pellentesque pellentesque, mi ut dictum suscipit, arcu nisl consequat urna, vitae auctor arcu quam a felis. Proin consectetur fermentum leo sit amet faucibus.
</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
<div class="column2">
Maecenas quis interdum est. Phasellus ut erat nec ligula blandit cursus. Nulla laoreet viverra interdum. Etiam sagittis porttitor elit id egestas. Morbi at nunc turpis, ut interdum magna. Nam eget dui metus. In aliquet dui non nisl porttitor et pretium nisi tristique. Vivamus non eros ut ligula pharetra porta. Suspendisse suscipit dignissim nibh, vitae auctor ligula condimentum et. In sit amet ultrices sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {padding:30px;}
.wrapper {margin:30px auto;}
.column {width:50%;float:left;}
.column1 {padding-right:20px;}
.column2 {padding-left:20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the left block, set the left margin to auto. For the right block, set the right. Like this:

```
#leftBlock {
    margin-left: auto;
}

#rightBlock {
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This puts them back to back in the center of the screen.
To add space in between the blocks, set the other margin to some defined amount:

```
#leftBlock {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

#rightBlock {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```